# JBoss - How to have a fixed name for exploded war directory?

Tags: html, jsp, jboss

Is it possible to configure JBoss to have a fixed directory name for the exploded war present inside tmp directory?  On every restart, the exploded war directories name changes with a random string is appended to them.

In JBoss 6, we have the following structure for our war file my-project.war:

JBOSS_HOME\server\default\tmp\vfs\automount8sc4d112587f64c\my-project.war-98eea116d17f4a53

What I want is: Can we have the above path name fixed for all restarts and deployments?

We could not bookmark the jsp/html/js/css files in our text editors due to this.

In WebLogic server, there is a fixed directory structure for all restarts and deployments.  It is very convenient for quick HTML/CSS/JavaScript coding.  Can we have something like that in JBoss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to reference the *temp* directory of jboss where the application server *unzips* war-files, etc.

Try to unzip your war file, name the folder `<your-project>.war` and move it to the deploy folder. Unless jboss does not need to unpack it, the files (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) should be delivered from this place.

Comment: A `touch deploy/your_project.war` may be needed to reload code changes.

Comment: That's not necessary if there are no code changes. For example, a change to CSS can be made visible without redeploying. If in development make sure to have the development flag [1] to true (which is the default value) `[1] http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html`

Comment: Thanks powerMicha for the response.  I was looking for some config changes at JBoss end that makes the tmp directory static.  However, your suggestion has solved my problem.  Thanks a lot.